# error using UNC name in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, unc

I have an IIS web site that reads files, some on the same server and some on other servers, using UNC names. This has been running on one of our servers for years and works fine. Now that server is being decommissioned so I need to move the app to a new server, and on the new server, I get "access denied" errors whenever I use a UNC name.

But here's the funny part: Trying to read a file on the same server where the app is running, if I give the name in conventional windows style, d:\somedir\somefile, it works fine. But if I reference the exact same file with a UNC name, \myserver\d$\somedir\somefile, it fails. So the problem can't be the permissions on the file. And as I can't use UNC names to read files on the same server where the app is running, the issue can't be anything about access between servers.

Oh, I can access the files by UNC name in Windows explorer (while signed in with my personal user id, not the id of the app pool).

The same app works when run from a different server, and it is accessing files on 5 different servers besides itself. I am quite certain that I did not change any security settings on those other servers when I wrote this app, though of course I might have been lucky and they were coincidentally set to values that worked for me.

The app pool, old and new, is set to user ApplicationPoolIdentity. The app has no logins, purely anonymous. (It's running on an internal network not accessible outside the company, it's all read-only, and it doesn't access any credit card information or anything like that, so security is not a big issue.)

Answer (score 0):

You may use Procmon.exe(from SysinternalsSuite) to check why it fails to open the file(probably credential problem).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I sort of figured out my own problem. On the server where it was working, I had impersonation implemented, so that it was impersonating a user who had different access rights than ApplicationPoolIdentify.

(I apparently made the change and never committed it back to SVN. So when I did a check-out on the new server I didn't pick it up. Arggh, I just spent hours searching for the solution to a problem that I had already solved a year ago. Bad enough to spend hours on a problem that someone else has already solved ...)